# nginx location excluding a particular request

Tags: nginx, regex

On WordPress admin, I have basic http authentication for nginx by using this inside nginx config:

```
location ^~ /wp-login.php {
        auth_basic           "Restricted Area: WordPress";
        auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/wp.htpasswd;
        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
}
```

Now this works but I need to add an exclusion to it for `wp-login.php?action=postpass`

I learnt from this [article](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/understanding-nginx-server-and-location-block-selection-algorithms) how nginx chooses which location block will be used to serve a particular request. `^~` being used to override any rules that we might have, I think I need to specify in a manner by which there is a regex rule and an exact rule, which should do the desired job.

This is what makes most sense to me, but it doesn't work:

```
location = /wp-login.php?action=postpass {
        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
}

location ~* /wp-login.php {
        auth_basic           "Restricted Area: WordPress";
        auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/wp.htpasswd;
        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
}
```

Also, tried other random combinations but no luck at all. Important to mention that basic auth should be in use when the request url is either just `wp-login.php` or anything behind it in URL, except `?action=postpass`

Please advice! Thanks in advance!

Comment: The problem here is that `location` uses normalized URIs that don't include query arguments.

Comment: @TeroKilkanen yep realized that from the answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

something like this should work

```
set $shouldauth "Restricted Area: WordPress";
if ($arg_action ~* postpass) {
  set $shouldauth off;
}
location ~* /wp-login.php {
  auth_basic           $shouldauth;
  auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/wp.htpasswd;
  include /etc/nginx/fastcgi.conf;
  fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
}
```